# Contact create using People API not support Internet call field

Tags: google-people-api

How to set Internet Call field value. I can't see any property related to internet call field in google people API.
refer the screenshot.I mean that field 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no current field exposed in the People API for the internet call field. This should be added soon.

Edited:
The field is now exposed as [sip address](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#sipaddress) field